# Reading a csv line. Problem with the last element

Tags: c++

I have the following function

```
void get_inspva(const std::string line){
     std::cout<<") "<<line<<std::endl;
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string lineStream;
    while (getline(iss,lineStream,',')){
       std::cout<<"["<<lineStream<<"]"<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

When I have a line like this:

```
a_line="1618378741,521574939,1618378741.55,36.10726662693096,139.97386621160913,57.3723646402359,-1.9803314791186484,-0.5150965223798682,0.021916236872909,-0.02259244492482216,0.09830296322174402,3.404935980746039,GOOD";
```

and I call `get_inspva(a_line)` I get

```
[1618378741]
[521574939]
[1618378741.55]
[36.10726662693096]
[139.97386621160913]
[57.3723646402359]
[-1.9803314791186484]
[-0.5150965223798682]
[0.021916236872909]
[-0.02259244492482216]
[0.09830296322174402]
[3.404935980746039]
]GOOD
```

Why is the last cout not working as it should?

EDIT:

The lines I am getting them from a csv file like

```
   std::ifstream file(input_file);
   std::string input_line;

    int i=0;
    while(getline(file,input_line)){
     //   std::cout<<i<<") "<<input_line<<std::endl;
    // Here we process the input_line
    get_inspva(input_line);    

    }
    file.close();
```

Comment: I'm getting the correct output. ...[GOOD]. Are you doing any processes before which may affect the stdout? If so, you may try to reset the stream like this: std::cout<< std::dec <<"["<<lineStream<<"]"<<std::endl;

Comment: I added from where do I call the function. I still get the strange thing. I added `std::cout<<"ABCDS["<<lineStream<<"]"<<std::endl;` and now I get `]BCDS[GOOD`

Comment: Sadly I still can't reproduce the error. It's perfectly fine on my side and I've tried to compile/debug with g++ and gdb. Both give the correct output. Maybe there's something wrong with your environment while displaying it. Can you try to build an a.out exe with "g++ main.cpp" and then run the ./a.out executable from the terminal?